# How to parse JSON with an inconsistent data type?

Tags: json, bash, csv, parsing, jq

I need to create a `csv` report from a `JSON` file of the following structure (simplified as much as I saw fit):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "foo": {
        "item": {
          "value": "foo_good",
          "bar_id": "1"
        }
      },
      "bar": {
        "item": {
          "id": "1",
          "value": "bar_value_1a"
        }
      },
      "var": {
        "item": {
          "value": "var_value_1a",
          "bar_id": "1"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "456",
      "foo": {
        "item": [
          {
            "value": "foo_bad",
            "bar_id": "1"
          },
          {
            "value": "foo_good",
            "bar_id": "2"
          },
          {
            "value": "foo_good",
            "bar_id": "2"
          },
          {
            "value": "foo_bad",
            "bar_id": "3"
          },
          {
            "value": "foo_good",
            "bar_id": "4"
          }
        ]
      },
      "bar": {
        "item": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "value": "bar_value_2a"
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "value": "bar_value_2b"
          },
          {
            "id": "3",
            "value": "bar_value_2c"
          },
          {
            "id": "4",
            "value": "bar_value_2d"
          }
        ]
      },
      "var": {
        "item": [
          {
            "value": "var_value_2a",
            "bar_id": "1"
          },
          {
            "value": "var_value_2b",
            "bar_id": "2"
          },
          {
            "value": "var_value_2c",
            "bar_id": "3"
          },
          {
            "value": "var_value_2d",
            "bar_id": "4"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**Data structure:**

1. `foo.item` and `var.item` are connected to `bar.item` with `bar_id`
2. One or more `foo.item` point to one `bar.item`
3. Multiple `foo.item` pointing to the same `bar.item` will have the same `foo.item.value`
4. Exactly one `var.item` points to one `bar.item`
5. All items are sorted by `bar_id`
6. The format is **inconsistent**. `bar.item` is an object if there is only one item, it's an array otherwise (applies to `foo.item` and `var.item` as well)
7. I am stuck with this format

**Output report:**

1. Process all `data` objects
2. Create report for each `bar.item` that does **not** have any corresponding `foo.item` with a value `foo_bad`
3. The output format: `.id, .bar.item.value, .var.item.value`

---

**My attempt:**

The temporary `jq` script I am currently using discards multiple `bar.item` etc. and creates mere estimation of the real data:

```
.data[]
| .foo.item |= if type=="array" then .[0] else . end
| .bar.item |= if type=="array" then .[0] else . end
| .var.item |= if type=="array" then .[0] else . end
| select(.foo.item.value != "foo_bad")
| [.id,.bar.item.value,.var.item.value]
| @csv
```

Which outputs the following:

```
"123","bar_value_1a","var_value_1a"
```

---

**Desired output:**

```
"123","bar_value_1a","var_value_1a"
"456","bar_value_2b","var_value_2b"
"456","bar_value_2d","var_value_2d"
```

I prefer using `jq` although I do not insist on it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you begin by ensuring that .foo.item, .bar.item, and .var.item are always arrays.  This could be done using the following helper function:

```
def w: if type=="array" then . else [.] end;
```

Your jq filter would then begin as follows:

```
.data[]
| .foo.item |= w
| .bar.item |= w
| .var.item |= w
```

What you do next depends on what you want to do with all these arrays, but I have verified that the following produces the result you've indicated you want:

```
.data[]
| .foo.item |= w
| .bar.item |= w
| .var.item |= w
| range(0; .foo.item | length) as $i
| select(.foo.item[$i].value != "foo_bad")
| select(.bar.item[$i].value)
| [.id,.bar.item[$i].value,.var.item[$i].value]
| @csv
```

Comment: Hm hm, since there can be more `foo.item` pointing to the same `bar.item`, I don't think this approach that seems to rely on one `foo.item` pointing to just one `bar.item` will work. For example by changing the 4th `foo.item` in the 2nd `data` object to `foo_bad`, your code will produce undesired results. Maybe my question is not clear enough? :) But thanks, your code points me in the right direction anyway. The helper function makes the code much more readable!

Comment: As I indicated, I don't understand your actual requirements. My guess is you'll want to add `range(0; .bar.item | length) as $j` and/or `range(0; .var.item | length) as $k`

Comment: I simply don't want to include `bar.item`s that have **any** `foo.item`s with value `foo_bad` pointing to them. So if I change the 4th `foo.item` in the 2nd `data` object to `foo_bad`, I don't want a report for `bar.item` with `id` equal to `3`. Is that perhaps clearer now? :) I understand that the input data is fairly large so I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: So...I forgot to mention one important thing: if there are more `foo.item`s pointing to the same `bar.item`, they will all have the same `foo.item.value`. So simply adding `| .foo.item |= unique_by(.bar_id)` solves the problem. I shall edit my requirements and you can edit your question. I will gladly accept it as a solution. Thanks again.